# xcodeでsplash画面の画像を挿入したいです。

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

行いたいこと
xcodeでsplash画面の画像を挿入したいです。

問題
ですが、launch images sourceが見当たりません。
どうしたら良いのでしょうか?

launch images sourceが表示されないです

[image: xcodeの表示です]

Comment: 海外の同サイトで、同様の質問がありました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58186505/xcode-launch-image-source
こちらでは解決しているようです。問題解決の参考になれば幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

もう既に回答済みかと思いますが、この件iOS13から導入されました「All-screen Support」を満たすためにSplash画像の利用から、「LaunchScreen.storyboard」の利用に方向転換しています。
Splash画像を利用したアプリは今後は申請も通らなくなることになります。

LaunchScreen.storyboardを利用してスプラッシュを組みたる方向で実装された方がいいと思います。

以下のようにAppleからはアナウンスされていました。

> "Starting April 30, 2020, new apps must use an Xcode storyboard to provide the app’s launch screen. In addition, new apps that run on iPhone must support all iPhone screens and new apps that run on iPad must support all iPad screens."

Comment: cubick♦様　校正をありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0):

[teratailでの回答があったので、こちらからのurl で確認してください](https://teratail.com/questions/246700#reply-357425)

Comment: asaiさん、わざわざ回答でリンクを貼ってくださりありがとうございます。ただリンクだけだとリンク切れが起きるだけでこの回答の価値が無くなってしまいます。もしよければリンク先の内容をご自身の言葉でまとめた内容を書いてくださいませんでしょうか。リンクはあくまで補助的なものであると嬉しいです。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。